# get list of sections from ini-file using shell (sed/awk)

Tags: sed, awk, ini

I want to create a var from the section names of an ini file like:

```
[foo]
; ...

[bar]
; ...

[baz:bar]
;...
```

now I need a var like

```
SECTIONS="foo bar baz"
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm now using this construct, don't need to know if a section exists. just read it, if it's empty it does not exist.

```
INI_FILE=test.ini

function ini_get
{

    eval `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' \
        -e 's/;.*$//' \
        -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' \
        -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' \
        -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" \
    < $INI_FILE \
    | sed -n -e "/^\[$1\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^;].*\=.*/p;}"

    echo ${!2}
}


IP=$(ini_get 50001 ip)
PORT=$(ini_get 50001 port)
echo $IP:$PORT
```

Answer (score 2):

One line solution could be:

```
export SECTIONS=`grep "^\[" test.ini |sort -u | xargs | tr '\[' ' ' | tr '\]' ' ' `
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SECTIONS=$(crudini --get your.ini | sed 's/:.*//')
```